# Lacking troll behavior detection

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to point out to the admins a trolling attitude not yet prevented by the StackOverflow system:

In the comments below this answer *(link removed since the referenced discussion was removed by a moderator)* ...

- a user suggested a flaw.
- I mentioned that the (possibly flawed) code would still solve the problem at hand.
- He commented that he will down-vote for that.
- I edited my answer - but also pointed out, that he could have done it himself.

In the discussion in the comments thereafter, the user made it very clear, that he was following this way of commenting on purpose to **force** the asker to acknowledge his suggestions.

I was audacious enough to point out to him, that this behaviour is not particularly endorsed here, so he started to delete his comments **and by the same token** citing my comments in his replies, making sure I do not cowardly cover my traces like he does.

Comment: If you think that's trolling, well... Good luck with your time on SO and the rest of the internet. The guy is trying to teach you how to use the site.

Comment: "Lacking troll behavior detection" Wanna write one?

Comment: Did he delete his comments?  Or were they flagged and got deleted?

Comment: @Mysticial Are you saying [this](https://xkcd.com/386/) is how to use SO?

Comment: @BoltClock As far as I can see, SO is not open source at this point of time, so how could I?

Comment: I smell a troll alright, but it isn't the person you're accusing.

Comment: "Trolling" might be the most misused word of 2015. When somebody disagrees with you, **that is not trolling**. When somebody downvotes you, and then refuses to retract their downvote after you argue with them, **that is not trolling**.

Comment: I have no context, but it seems the user gave you the opportunity to fix your answer, that speaks quite good about that user... he's not a *downvote and move on* type of user, he actually gives time to read and analyze and help other user's responses/questions

Answer (score -40, accepted):

After marinating on this issue for a bit, my suggestion is:

> A commenter should have to wait one hour until s/he can (re)vote on the question or answer he commented.

This leaves the possibility of expressing one's opinion with a vote and *then* giving an explanatory comment, while it inhibits the possibility to use the vote as a reaction to behaviour.

Also, one might rather edit oneself than wait one hour to "get one's own back".

Comment: We really don't need to change the way the system works because you disagree with one person's vote on one answer

Comment: @Clive I'm not asking for change. The answer is a suggestion, also intended to address BoltClock's question.

Comment: So it's not a suggestion for change then? What is it?

Comment: @Clive A *suggestion* is something you can take or leave. If I was *asking for change*, I would be insisting on implementation, which I'm not.

Comment: Ok, I see what's happening here. Off I go...

Comment: *"while it inhibits the possibility to use the vote as a reaction to behaviour"* Why would you want to inhibit a downvoter from retracting said vote after you fix the problem? that makes no sense.

Answer (score 27):

Explaining to you why he feels your answer is harmful is not trolling.  (Even if he's wrong about the problems with the answer which, based on your responses, doesn't even appear to be the case.)  That's just constructive criticism, which is *very much welcome here*.

You should be thankful that this user took some time out of his day to help you improve your answer.

Comment: Downvoting as a punishment for me not adding his suggestion is trolling to me.

Comment: @arney Downvoting an answer you perceive as incorrect or harmful is exactly what is expected of users. Even if he was wrong, if he felt your answer was wrong and you weren't updating it to what he felt was correct, he was completely within his rights to downvote.

Comment: @arney No, it's not.  It's indicating to other readers that the answer is of low quality, which is exactly what votes are for.  The only problem I have with that action is that he really should have downvoted right from the start, rather than waiting for your refusal to update the post.

Comment: @arney That's not trolling. If you want us to troll you, speak up and we will gladly do so.

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't think that's how it works...

Comment: @BoltClock shhhhhhhhh...

Comment: @Kendra I agree that you should down-vote an answer you consider bad. But the above mentioned user did not. The down-vote was made as a reaction on the user's hurt feeling of not being taken as serious as he aspires to,

Comment: @arney and how would you know that? Are you on the pre-Alpha for the Mind-Reading Add-in?

Comment: @arney He made it very clear in his comments that he felt your answer was harmful, so no, he was downvoting because the answer merited the downvote (in his opinion).  This is about as clear of a case of that as one can possibly find.  The fact that you've decided that *you don't care about the problems with your answer* and that you *can't be bothered to fix them*, and are instead demanding someone else fix it, is honestly pretty appalling to me, and clearly was what gave the user sufficient motivation to downvote.

Comment: @Mysticial if there are going to be continual troll-requests, there ought to be a specific review queue so that we can all rate the request by tag, stupidity etc. and pick out the most rewarding posts to troll.

Comment: @arney From my point of view, the user was trying to be nice to you by not downvoting your answer immediately, and then only decided to do so later when you refused to improve it. He very well could have instead downvoted and not left a comment at all, thus not helping you improve it.